# Linux mmap() MAP_PRIVATE allocation

Tags: linux, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, swap, mmap

On Linux 4.6 when a program code calls [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_PRIVATE`flag, does the kernel keep track of the memory being allocated against a "system commit limit" -- should that memory be swapped from RAM ?

My question is the analogous of the Windows's behavior for pagefile-backed sections.
Thanks.

Comment: Linux generally overcommits, I don't think there's a commit limit.

Comment: It detects running out of swap space when it needs to copy a page to swap.

Comment: So there is _not_ a check on committed swap space upon mmap() returning from call. Eventually the system will run out of swap space during normal execution at runtime.

Comment: Only if you keep allocating memory forever. This isn't normal, and it's usually not hard to configure your machine so it never runs out.

Comment: @Barmar You mean fair programs should actually unmap() the memory they allocate through mmap().

Comment: That's usually what happens. Or the program exits and its mappings go away.

Comment: This isn't really specific to `mmap()`. The same issue arises if you just keep allocating memory with `malloc()`.